# PHP + Echo Data Routinely

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code working 'successfully' to display URL's:

```
     <?php 
       for ($i = 0; $i <= $json->domaincount; $i++) {
         echo '<td class="domainList"><a href="'.$json->$i.'" target="_blank">'.$json->$i.'</a></td>';
       }    
     ?>
```

Every forth echo I want to also

```
 echo </tr><tr>
```

to start a new line in the table.
Is there an easy way to know which is every forth count?
I have $i which increments from 0 up so when it gets to 3, 7, 11 etc I need to change table line.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( ( $i + 1 ) % 4 == 0 ) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
```

This is using the modulus operator.  It divides a number and returns the remainder, so 7 % 4 = 3 (because 4 fits in once, and three is left over) and 8 % 4 = 0 (because 4 fits in evenly and there are no left overs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $json->domaincount;) {
        echo '<td class="domainList"><a href="'.$json->$i.'" target="_blank">'.$json->$i.'</a></td>';
        if (!(++$i & 3))
            echo '</tr><tr>'; 
    }    
?>
```

`!($i & 3)` is just a quick way of writing `$i % 4 === 0` without having to use modulus. You can only use that trick for modding by powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Look into modulo operands (% in PHP). So the check that i % 4 == 0 would give you every fourth row.